# How to access a specific p tag while using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello everyone I'm having trouble while using BeautifulSoup , indeed i don't succeed to access the information that I want, here is my code :

```
import nltk 

import requests 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import time 

from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

url = 'https://www.richter-helm.eu/index.php?id=26'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

results_date=soup.find_all(class_='csc-textpic-text')[1]


print(results_date)
```

The output of this code is that :

```
</p> class="csc-textpic-text"><p class="bodytext">2021
</p>lass="bodytext">10. March 2021
</p>lass="bodytext">The NDR reports on the important role of Richter-Helm BioLogics as a Germany-based manufacturer of a DNA vaccine to support the Pharma industry and the fight against COVID-19. <a class="external-link-new-window" href="https://www.ndr.de/nachrichten/schleswig-holstein/Corona-In-Bovenau-wird-an-einem-neuen-Impfstoff-gearbeitet,bovenau124.html" target="_blank" title="Opens internal link in current window">See and read more</a> about our contribution to the fight against Corona. 
<p class="bodytext"> </p>
</p>lass="bodytext">15. February 2021
```

and what I want is the second 'p' with the information : '10. March 2021'
however I don't know how to access this information, I tried : print(results_date.find('p')) instead of print(results_date) but it gives me the first 'p' meaning it gives me: 'p class="bodytext">2021' and it's stil not what I want, if anyone can help me it will be very nice.

Comment: Your HTML is not valid, e.g., `</p>lass="bodytext">`. Please fix. Did you mess it up somehow with a blanket search and replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`:nth-of-type(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) CSS Selector.

To use a CSS Selector, use the [`.select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method instead of `.find_all()`.

---

In your example, find the `id="c51"`, and then the second `p` tag.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.richter-helm.eu/index.php?id=26"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

# The following will select the `id="c51"`, and than the second `p` tag.
print(soup.select_one("#c51 p:nth-of-type(2)").text)
```

Output:

```
10. March 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve the problem, I tried to find the information that I wanted by accessing the 'bodytext' class, so instead of using :
results_date=soup.find_all(class_='csc-textpic-text')[1]
I tried :
results_date=soup.find_all(class_='bodytext')[8]
and the output is what I wanted, the problem is that I have to find the good 'bodytext' element in order to find the information that I want, So I would definitely recommand
the: nth-of-type(n) CSS Selector as MendelG told me to do so